# Do hive queries executed via HUE survive a disconnect?

Tags: hive, hue

If I fire a query to HIVE using HUE. The query is taking a long time.
Can I disconnect my browser and go home? some back tomorrow and refresh the same page and see the result?

Or should I leave the machine connected with the browser open so that I don't lose the query/MR results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I found the answer. last night I ran all my queries and went home and today morning reconnected my machine to the network and refreshed the results. I can see query results.

So we don't need to wait for the query to finish to get the results.

Comment: Correct, Hue is just a view on top of the cluster, so logging out does not affect anything.

Comment: I also learnt that this is not very reliable. sometimes I get error "query results have expired" So it only works sometimes while other times, query results are lost.